# how to calculate number of values in combined columns, by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr to calculate the number of 9s **and** 10s in columns 5 and 6 **combined**, grouped by gender. I would like the result to look like this:

desired result

[image]

What is the code? My current code isn't working:

```
Data %>% group_by(Gender) %>% sum(c([5,6]) == 9 | c([5,6]) == 10)
```

Comment: Hi Amanda, for us to help we will need the `Data` data frame you are working with (perhaps you can share it here using `dput`) that clearly shows the `Gender` column. It looks like you are including a command that should not be in a pipe but to know for sure we need a reproducible example. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr` works with column names, not numbers. Replace `c([5, 6])` with `c(name_of_fifth_column, name_of_sixth_column)`. (And, in all cases, column numbers have to be *of* something. `[5, 6]` is a syntax error. `df[5, 6]` is the 5th row, 6th column of `df`. `df[c(5, 6)]` is the 5th and 6th column of `df`). And put it in `summarize()`.

This should work:

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(Gender) %>% 
  summarize(Number_of_9s_and_10s = sum(c(name_of_fifth_column, name_of_sixth_column) %in% c(9, 10)))
```

If that doesn't work, please share some sample data.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the answer I was looking for. I've been trying to figure this out the whole night (got a time-sensitive project), so really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad it helped! If this resolves your question, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark in the left margin next to the answer. This indicates that the question is resolved, and gives us each a little reputation point boost.